# Include action, Include Directive and hash codes of the request objects?

Tags: java, jsp, web, hash, include

So here is the little code I have:

index.jsp:

```
Hashcode of request object in main page: <%= request.hashCode() %>
<%@ include file="includedirective.jsp"%>
<jsp:include page="includeaction.jsp" />
```

includeDirective.jsp:

```
Hashcode of request object in include directive: <%= request.hashCode() %>
```

includeAction.jsp:

```
Hashcode of request object in include action: <%= request.hashCode() %>
```

So after 3 refreshes on the page, the output:

```
Hashcode of request object in main page: 1646052972
Hashcode of request object in include directive: 1646052972
Hashcode of request object in include action: 318408832

Hashcode of request object in main page: 1646052972
Hashcode of request object in include directive: 1646052972
Hashcode of request object in include action: 618720209

Hashcode of request object in main page: 1646052972
Hashcode of request object in include directive: 1646052972
Hashcode of request object in include action: 412698049
```

Here are my following questions:

1) Why the hash code of the request object in index.jsp is not changing with every refresh? Should not a new request object be created with every request?

2) Why the hash code of the request object in include action is changing every time I refresh the page?

3) I understand that there are 2 different request objects when I include the page using the action.. If I add this in includeAction.jsp:

```
<%
request.setAttribute("actionAttribute", "Attribute set in includeAction");
%>
```

And then in index.jsp I try:

```
<%
    out.print(request.getAttribute("actionAttribute"));
%>
```

I am expecting **NOT TO** see the value of "actionAttribute" but it is there? How come?

Answer (score 1):

Include directive insert the code into main.jsp before the container make the "translation". Generated servlet cotains the code of both files main.jsp and includeDirective.jsp.

When you use include action, the response of includeAction.jsp is insert into main.jsp but not include in the translation. The code of includeDirective.jsp isn't into generated servlet.

1) The JSP translate to Sevlet in the first request.

2) Include action make a new translation in each request.

3) The request object it's the same for main.jsp and includeAction.jsp. If you set an attribute in includeAction runtime, you can see when the includeAction "response" to main.jsp.

Try print attribute before    `<jsp:include page="includeaction.jsp" />`

Comment: If they are the same request object then why do they have different hash codes?

Comment: It's true, are different objects. The container create a object Request, when you use jsp:include create other type request ApplicationHttpRequest. It's a internal request but all attributes are replicated.

If you print request.getClass() in both jsp, you can see two differents classes ApplicationHttpRequest and RequestFacade

Comment: Hmm very interesting. But why is index.jsp is translated only once but include action translates every time after every request?

Comment: The reason is the index.jsp print the response that other jsp generated.

If you use de include directive, jsp is translated only once.

Remember, the container translate jsp to a Servlet (Java code) and compile. It's a expensive work.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are assuming hashCode means memory address and hence the same
   object.
2. However, hashCode could change for the same object.
3. HashCode method is often overridden and it is usually derieved from
   the data in the object.
4. So, if any data changes in the request object the hashCode could
   change.
5. So as the request object is passed on if the server changes some
   data in the request object, the hashCode could keep changing with
   time.
6. Try printing the same operations in reverse order and tell us what
   happens.

Refer - [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

Answer (score -1):

Any particular reason why you need this?

> 1) Why the hash code of the request object in index.jsp is not
>   changing with every refresh?

Hard to tell, depends on the hashCode method implementation. You should find out, what class in your servlet container implements request, decompile it and analyze hashcode method.

> 2) Why the hash code of the request object in include action is
>   changing every time I refresh the page?

Same as above - implementation dependent. And you should be aware that each container may implement this in different way as hashCode method contract is not defined in the specification

> 3) I understand that there are 2 different request objects. [..] I am
>   expecting NOT TO see the value of "actionAttribute" but it is there?
>   How come?

They are not exactly 2 different objects. If you take a step back and take a look at RequestDispatcher interface, there is an `include(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)` method there. jsp:include is translated to that method call, so actually your first request is a parameter to second call. Whether it is same request or wrapped in some other class is again container dependent. However any attributes you set in the request object will be visible in both places as from logical point of view it is the same request.

**UPDATE**
Just to confirm, what I wrote earlier, I've made a test on my web container. Here are the results. In my web container hashcode is the same in all three places for every request:

```
Hashcode of request object in main page: -798420760 
Hashcode of request object in include directive: -798420760 
Hashcode of request object in include action: -798420760

Hashcode of request object in main page: -798420760 
Hashcode of request object in include directive: -798420760 
Hashcode of request object in include action: -798420760
```

In my container SAME request object is used in index and in include action. This is another point to confirm that its implementation dependent and answer to your question is platform dependent.

Comment: I do not think the fact that hashcode changes for one request object but for one other is because of the implementation.

Comment: You didn't provide any data on which server and version you are running this. If you would provide that it would be actually very easy to check. You print request.getClass().getName() in each of your file to check actual implementation, then decompile the class and read hashcode method.